# Sampling methods for Text datasets (NLP)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nlp, dataset, statistics

I am working on two text datasets, one is having 68k text samples and other is having 100k text samples. I have encoded the text datasets into bert embedding.

```
Text sample > 'I am working on NLP' ==> bert encoding ==> [0.98, 0.11, 0.12....nth]
               # raw text 68k                              # bert encoding [68000, 1024]
```

I want to try different custom NLP models on these embeddings, but dataset large to test the model's performance quickly.

To check different models quickly, the best way is to take a small subset of dataset from the entire population and feed it to different algorithms. At last, choose the top algorithms to fit the entire dataset.

I am planning to sample at least 10k samples subset from 68k dataset and 10k subset from 100k dataset. I could select randomly 10k from 68k but that method is not the best way to sample.

Any advice on how to sample embeddings(text) from 68k samples while maintaining the probability distribution of the original population and how many samples would be enough for one sample subset?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to enumerate each piece of text and then randomly pick an integer from the list of the integers. This will proportionally sample the empirical distribution.

"How many samples?" depends on the diversity of the text dataset. If the pieces are similar then the standard advice of a minimum of 30 samples is applicable. If each piece is unique, then you'll have to look at each piece.